# Get current URL in Chrome using Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have just started developing chrome extension ( Using chrome 34).

My aim is to check for a ID attribute in a site by opening it in multiple languages.

For instance, whenever I open that website, and click on my extension link. The extension should open the website in multiple languages in background, and check if a html "ID" exists.

As a start, I want to get the current URL for that site.

`manifest.json` -

```
{
 "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Hello World!",
  "description": "My extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
 },

 "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
]

 }
```

My `popup.html` is

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="currentUrl.js"/>
```

and `currentUrl.js` is

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
  function(tabs){
    alert(tabs[0].url);
  }
 );
```

But it is not working to alert the current URL. Whenever I click extension, just a small blank window appears.

Comment: Right click the button and choose "Inspect popup". Does the console show any error or warning or anything? Also, do not forget to add a DOCTYPE to any HTML file you create - start any HTML file with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, or else it would be rendered in a legacy compatibility mode, called Quirks Mode that adds some non standard, unexprected behaviors.

Comment: Console log shows nothing. Added DOCTYPE.still no luck.

Comment: Keep using the "Inspect popup". Add `debugger;` before the `alert` and see what the `tabs` variable holds when the debugger breaks.

Comment: Change your script tag to: `<script type="text/javascript" src="currentUrl.js"></script>`

Comment: I see you already found out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463220/chrome-extension-access-dom-after-chrome-tabs-update

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/17379190/2336725