# Getting current tab url after click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want the current tab url to be display in the pop up after clicking the extension. I have a popup html and popup.js. For testing purpose, I been trying to alert the tab url instead of replacing the html element.

Manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "first extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Share it!"
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    URL:
    <p>www.blahblah.com</p>
    <form>
        Title:<br />
        <input type="text" name="title"><br />
        Description:<br />
        <textarea rows="4"></textarea><br />
        <button>Get</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){
        alert(tab.url);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to follow the suggested workaround in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18436323/5832311). Try this [query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) `chrome.tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback)` which will get all tabs that have the specified properties, or all tabs if no properties are specified.

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    console.log(tabs[0].url);
});
```

Here another thread which might also help: [How to get current URL in Chrome on click of the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379190/how-to-get-current-url-in-chrome-on-click-of-the-button)

Comment: Note that this approach requires `"tabs"` permission, `"activeTab"` may not be enough.